# Can't step into QT Source code on Ubuntu

Tags: qt, ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need to step into Qt sources (my IDE is Qt Creator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049578/need-to-step-into-qt-sources-my-ide-is-qt-creator)

I built QT 4.8.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS(64 bit) with the following configuration options:

./configure -webkit-debug -debug-and-release -opensource -openssl -I ~/openssl-1.0.0d/include

When I debug and trace my own application built with the compiled version of qt4.8.3, I can't step into the QT source code.

I check the files under the Qt installation folder: /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.3/lib, I only see a single libXXXXX.so.4.8.3 file for each compiled lib. I was expecting to see separate libraries for release and debug version.

Whenever I create a new instance of QScriptEngine in my app, it immediately crashes. Therefore, I would like to step into QT source code to see what is going on. Please advise what I can do to step into Qt source code on ubuntu.

Comment: If you read the information provided by ./configure -help, you will see that -debug-and-release is only supported on Mac. Therefore, it is normal, on Ubuntu, that you do not see a separate library for release and debug versions.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I should have seen that!